# What's the difference between "Hello" foreach (x = x * _.toLong ) and "Hello" foreach (x *= _.toLong ) in scala?

Tags: scala

What's the difference between `"Hello" foreach (x = x * _.toLong)` and  `"Hello" foreach (x *= _.toLong)` in Scala?

Doesn't work:

```
scala> var x : Long = 1
x: Long = 1
scala> "Hello" foreach (x = x * _.toLong )
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x.$times(x$1.toLong))
   "Hello" foreach (x = x * _.toLong )
```

Works:

```
scala> "Hello" foreach (x *= _.toLong )
scala> xbtebh
res89: Long = 9415087488
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
"Hello" foreach (x = x * _.toLong)
```

is actually expanded by the compiler into this:

```
"Hello" foreach (x = x * (x$1 => x$1.toLong))
```

Obviously, multiplying a `Long` with an anonymous function that invokes `toLong()` on its argument doesn't make much sense. Of course, writing the expanding version yourself works fine, e.g. `"Hello" foreach (y => x = x * y.toLong)`.

In your second expression `"Hello" foreach (x *= _.toLong )` there are two expansions that need to be done by the compiler: one that expands the underscore like in the previous example and one that expands `x *= y` into `x = x * y`. Obviously first one is happening before the second one, so the compiler sees `(x *= _.toLong)` as a single expression so instead of expanding to `(x *= (x$1 => x$1.toLong))`, it expands to `x$1 => (x *= x$1.toLong)`. I can't really point a finger at it since I would need to dig into Scala specification and compiler internals, but now you have a clue about what's causing this behaviour.

My personal advice is to use underscore only in trivial situations, such as `List(1, 2, 3).map(_.toLong)`, and always write the full function in situations like yours, e.g. `"Hello" foreach (arg => x = x * arg.toLong)`.

Also note that using side-effects and mutable values is a big no-no in Scala. Here's an improved version of your code:

```
val result = "Hello".foldLeft(1: Long)((x, c) => x * c.toLong)
```

Comment: "Also note that using side-effects and mutable values is a big no-no in Scala." - this is not quite true. Scala is an impure object-functional language. You can happily throw side-effects everywhere and the type checker will not complain.

Comment: I'm not saying type checker would complain. I'm just saying that especially because it's allowed, it can lead to bad design and is discouraged. If Scala weren't impure, my comment would be meaningless because the language itself wouldn't allow it anyway.

Comment: When the underlying basis of the language allows side-effects and mutation, then your statement is not quite true. Even Odersky himself is on record stating that he is not a fan of pure functional programming (which is what your statement refers to) and promotes a more relaxed version of "functional programming". Trying to adhere to purity by convention, in my opinion, is an uphill battle and Scala is selling something here by not being very good at it.

Comment: I do agree that mutations and side-effects can be handy, e.g. in performance-critical implementations of data structures which don't expose the mutability in their API (it's an implementation detail). However, in case OP is a beginner who is learning Scala, I think that advice on prefering vals to vars, fold/map/flatMap to foreach and favoring side-effect-free methods is a good one. It's a general guidiline that should be broken only when there is a good reason for it. As interesting as it may be, I would like to stop this discussion because it's not really relevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the first case you are using direct attribution with `=` which will obviously fail.

If you look at the signature of `foreach`, you can see that it's expecting a function.

In the first scenario you are simply not providing one, because you are not respecting lambda syntax. The lambda syntax of the `f: A => U` expected by the `foreach` function is `x => x * 5` or something similar.

You are obviously not doing that, the real syntax there would be:

```
"Hello" foreach (ch => x = x * ch.toLong )
```

In the second instance you are using the shortform lambda, namely the fact that `col.foreach(x => x + 5)` can be re-written as `col.foreach(_ + 5)`, except you are reversing it to `col.foreach(5 + _)`, which is also a correct form of writing lambdas.

The `_` in your second example correctly takes the form of the current char in your string.

So this `"Hello" foreach (x *= _.toLong )` is actually `"Hello" foreach (ch => x *= ch.toLong )` but using the short-hand form for the lambda, that's why it works.

Comment: It's amazing what can get compiled by the Scala compiler sometimes.